# How can I make Tor and Polipo run (and automatically restart) using launchd on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, tor

I have no experience with launchd but would like to setup Tor and Polipo as a service that automatically restarts every 24 hours or so. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

For tor you can use this launchd plist to have it start at system launch. (No need for a user to be logged in which is ideal for servers and people running a bridge or node that shall be up 24/7.)

Save this file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.torproject.tor.plist` (You'll need root privileges for that so use `sudo`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.torproject.tor</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/path/to/your/binary/of/tor</string>
                <string>-f</string>
                <string>/path/to/your/torrc</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>userNameToRunTorUnder-UsuallyTorOrYourOwnUsershortname</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Replace the following information with the one matching your system:

*`/path/to/your/binary/of/tor`*
This is usually `/usr/local/bin/tor` if you have installed tor from source or `/Applications/Vidalia.app/Contents/MacOS/tor` if you want to use the tor binary from Vidalia. Or look for it with `which tor` on your system.

*`/path/to/your/torrc`*
If you're running tor as a separate user this should be in `.torrc` in that user's home directory. You need to specify the *absolute path* to this file. For example if your user is named *tor* and resides in `/Users/tor` then that path would be `/Users/tor/.torrc`

*`userNameToRunTorUnder-UsuallyTorOrYourOwnUsershortname`*
This is the username to run `tor` under. If you do have a separate user (which is likely to be named *tor*) then use that one, else you can use pretty much any other username. If this is just for yourself make it your own usershortname. (Aka what your home directory is named.)

Make sure the privileges of the launchd item are safe as required by launchd.

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.torproject.tor.plist
sudo chmod 755 /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.torproject.tor.plist
```

Then launch it with
    `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.torproject.tor.plist`

You can use a very similar item to launch polipo.
Save this Launchd item as `/Library/LaunchDaemons/fr.jussieu.pps.polipo.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>fr.jussieu.pps.polipo</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/path/to/your/binary/of/polipo</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>/path/to/your/polipo.conf</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>userNameToRunPolipoUnder-UsuallyPolipoOrYourOwnUsershortname</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Again replace the following information with the one matching your system:
*/path/to/your/binary/of/polipo*
If you want to use the one from Vidalia use /Applications/Vidalia.app/Contents/MacOS/polipo else find out where your polipo binary is with `which polipo`. (For example MacPorts does instal this in `/opt/local/bin/polipo`)

*`/path/to/your/polipo.conf`*
Again, if you want to use the file provided by Vidalia `/Applications/Vidalia.app/Contents/Resources/polipo.conf` or use the *absolute path* to your custom configuration.

*`userNameToRunPolipoUnder-UsuallyPolipoOrYourOwnUsershortname`*
This can be the same username that you run `tor` with, but it can also be a separate user. I like to have my daemons separated.

Again, make sure the privileges of the launchd item are safe as required by launchd.

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/fr.jussieu.pps.polipo.plist
sudo chmod 755 /Library/LaunchDaemons/fr.jussieu.pps.polipo.plist
```

Then launch it with
    `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/fr.jussieu.pps.polipo.plist`

Caveat:
This setup does *not* restart the daemons every 24h as requested. I don't think it is necessary as I have never had any problems with stability with `tor`. (I've been running nodes for several years on Mac OS X.)

`tor` does *not* handle system sleep at all. So if you put your Mac to sleep, you need to restart `tor` to have it reliably build circuits again.

This description is meant for Macs that are up and running anyway. It is possible to make this run as your user and only when you login graphically without requiring `root` privileges.

That should be it.

PS: Please keep in mind that `tor` is meant to allow access where blocking and cencorship occurs as well as anonymity and privacy online and [why running BitTorrent over `tor` isn't a good idea](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea).

Answer (score 0):

[Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/) is discontinued but still works and is the best tool to manage launchd if you have no experience.

Comment: The abandoned Lingon 2.1.1 still works fine under 10.6 SnowLeopard. There also is an updated version 2.2.1 for SnowLeopard available for 3.99€ in the Mac AppStore. http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/lingon/id411211026?mt=12